# Magento Changing Default Payment Method

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a function that runs raw SQL queries to our database in Magento. What the function does is changes the customer's default credit card to a value passed to the function. My question is how would I rewrite the function utilizing Magento models. The current function works, but we'd rather have it not be directly interfacing with SQL.

Here is the function:

```
public function setDefaultPayment($value)
{
    $customerId = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer()->getId();
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    $read = $write->query("SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code='customer'");
    $row = $read->fetch();
    $entity_type_id = $row['entity_type_id'];

    $read = $write->query("SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code='default_payment' AND entity_type_id = $entity_type_id");
    $row = $read->fetch();
    $attribute_id = $row['attribute_id'];

    $read = $write->query("SELECT * FROM customer_entity_int WHERE entity_type_id='$entity_type_id' AND attribute_id='$attribute_id' AND entity_id='$customerId'");
    if ($row = $read->fetch()) {
        $write->update(
            'customer_entity_int',
            array('value' => $value),
            "entity_type_id='$entity_type_id' AND attribute_id='$attribute_id' AND entity_id='$customerId'"
        );
    } else {
        $write->insert(
            'customer_entity_int',
            array(
                'entity_type_id' => $entity_type_id,
                'attribute_id' => $attribute_id,
                'entity_id' => $customerId,
                'value' => $value
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What native Magento class is your custom class extending?

Comment: The attribute `default_payment' where does that come from? An extension? Did you create that and how? - Normally credit card data isn't stored in Magento because 99% of the merchants running Magento are not PCI DSS compliant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard)

Comment: @codedge, I did not create this. I recently accepted a job at a company that used completely non-standard Magento practices, down to the point of replacing parts of the core of Magento itself. In other words, we're version locked to a specific version of magento (1.9). We are in the process of revising the site and making it somewhat standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read you code right, you want to update the customer attribute `default_payment` with a value given.

For that you need to:

- Load the customer by id
- Set the new value for the customer attribute `default_payment`
- Save the customer

```php
public function setDefaultPayment($value)
{
    $customerId = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer()->getId();
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
    $oldValue = $customer->getDefaultPayment(); // optional, just for checking
    $customer->setDefaultPayment($value);
    $customer->save();

}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. This gives me some insight into how to fix up some other functions we have which are also in SQL. Thanks!